# Query gives different output on different OS

Tags: java, mysql, windows, linux

I have written the following function in Java. This function returns current timestamp by executing a query. The function code is as follows :

```
private  String getTimeStamp(){
    String timeStamp=null;      
    try{
        String strQuery="select current_timestamp";
        PreparedStatement pmtQuery=con.prepareStatement(strQuery);
        ResultSet rsQuery=pmtQuery.executeQuery();
        rsQuery.next();
        timeStamp=rsQuery.getString(1);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Value of timeStamp : "+timeStamp);
    }catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println("SQL Exception in the getTimeStamp()");
    }       
    return timeStamp;
}
```

When I use this function on windows It gives proper out put and works fine.
Ex.

If execute above function in widows it gives timestamp like ex. 2011-06-01 17:05:03

but when I execute this function in Debina linux it gives timestamp as 
2011-06-01 17:05:03.0

It appends .0 to timestamp

Please guide me in this problem

```
1.why such different output comes on different system?

2.How to avoid this problem?

3.How to solve this problem?
```

I am using following configurations

windows

windows 7, Mysql database, Java 6

Linux

Debian linux, Mysql Database, Java 6

Thank You!

Comment: Try retrieving the parameter as a Date instead of String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%d/%m/%Y %hh%mm%ss')
```

**Note:**

*I wonder why you are querying to get the currentDate*

Comment: why? eventually to get the current date and **time** from the database server (as opposed to the current system ones). Or just an example to test/show the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem probably are different (default) settings of the JDBC drivers.

I would prefer fetching the timestamp as a `Timestamp` (subclass of `java.util.Date`):

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
...
Timestamp timeStamp;
...
timeStamp = rsQuery.getTimestamp(1);
```

This way you can control how to format it in the Java code as/if needed (e.g. using `SimpleDateFormat` or `String.format`).

Answer (score 0):

It's not portable, but you can use the DATE_FORMAT function:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i:%s');
```

Documentation is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Answer (score 0):

you can also use

```
SimpleDateFormat
```

Its a simple date formatter.